# Rails: How to compare previous value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

What I'd like to do is to display something when `category` column is changed.

But the last data doesn't display anything.

For example the data in the `Event` model is as below;

```
id  start_at  category
1   02:00     3
2   03:00     2
3   04:00     1
```

Although what I'd like to display as followings, the last data `02:00 (change category)` doesn't display.

```
04:00
03:00 (change category)
02:00 (change category)
```

**model**

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base    
  default_scope -> { order(category: :asc, start_at: :asc) }

  def previous
    Event.where("id < ?", self.id).order("category ASC, start_at ASC").first
  end
```

**view**

```
<% @events.each do |event| %>
    <% if event.previous %>
       <%= event.start_at %> (change category)<br>       
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

I know the reason why `02:00 (change category)` doesn't display (because the previous data doesn't exist).

It would be appreciated if you could give me how to realize what I'd like to do.

Comment: why don't you just remove the `if` ?, I mean, if you want to display that value and if the `if` is what's preventing it from being shown..., unless you're doing something else, but that I don't know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this with a simple variable and you don't need to do the extra database call...

```
<% category = nil %>
<% @events.each do |event| %>
    <% if event.category != category %>
       <%= event.start_at %> (change category)<br>   
       <% category = event.category %>    
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, @SteveTurczyn. It works! Thank you for understanding what I'd like to do.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what do you want to do.

If you just want to know the previous value, you could add one field to the model and whenever you update the start_at value you have to remember to update the old value field (which should start at nil or empty_string).

A more generic way to do this and remember old values for fields could be to generate a new table which points to different models attributes. This new table should contain at least: changeable_type:string, changeable_id:integer, attribute_name:string, attribute_value:string (id, created_at, updated_at are created by default). Then you could add to this event model

```
# in this example Change is the name of this new model, and it has -> belongs_to :changeable, polymorphic: true
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base    
  has_many :changes, as: :changeable
  default_scope -> { order(category: :asc, start_at: :asc) }
  after_save :store_old_start_at_value

  def store_old_start_at
    old_value = self.changes[:start_at]
    if old_value # 
      Change.create(changeable: self, attribute_name: 'start_at', attribute_value: old_value[0])
    end
  end

  def previous_start_values
    Change.where(changeable_type: self.class.name, changeable_id: self.id, attribute_name: 'start_at').map(&:attribute_value)
  end
end
```

- short version
  You can use the models change method on the after_save callback to store the old value. The code before leverages on this storing that value in a polymorphic table that can store any change on any table and any field of that table.